# Kerbal Gone Wild - Could a DIY team create a Mercury-scale orbital capsule?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, mission-design, materials

Given how much engineering has advanced since the days of the Mercury program, could a similarly scaled single-person orbital vehicle capable of repeatedly sustaining 48 hours in orbit realistically be constructed as a backyard/garage project by a dedicated and knowledgeable DIY team?

Comment: While cool at the moment this would be a very opinion based question, the intended site format is intended to produce a single 'right' answer which is tricky at the moment. Suggest defining a target capsule mass? If arbitrary mass is allowed this becomes quite feasible just by over-engineering everything. If constrained to the mass of the historical Mercury than answer is a solid no due the small margins. Would also be useful to define number of test launches before it flies manned - given a dozen or so test flights much becomes possible - if it has to work first go not so much.

Comment: Technology aside, you'd quickly get a visit from some serious men in black suits, regarding the *missile* you're building.

Comment: Are you talking about just the spacecraft, or an orbital booster as well?

Comment: Capsule only. Not necessarily a capsule form either, a mini X-37 or small-scale Dreamchaser would work.

Comment: Presumably building a capsule is much easier than a spaceplane! Because the spaceplane needs all of the capsule but also much more complicated aerodynamics than the capsule... (although they *may* be able to forego the parachute with a long enough runway).

Comment: Orbital vehicle only, no launcher under discussion. And no, parts need not be manufactured from scratch. Some solutions may only require off-the-shelf hardware, some may mean OTS with modification and surely some custom.
3D printing with metal can be leveraged for a project like this. There's so much possible now that was not possible then. Set aside questions of cost. It is possible?

Comment: Not sure how 3D printing would help much. I have heard of 3D printing of engine parts, but the launcher is excluded. The toughest part of a capsule may well be the heat shield - and due to the heat that it has to handle, I'm skeptical that 3D printing (which is largely though not entirely based on depositing melted materials in place) would help much with that.

Comment: If [these guys can do time travel in a garage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vD-yj9o664) then space travel should be a piece of cake

Comment: You might be interested in https://copenhagensuborbitals.com/missions/spica/, altough they only plan suborbital flights.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about Copenhagen. They're coming along, got a ways to go.

Answer (score 3):

(Too much for a comment)

You have excluded the launcher but there are still some very important unknowns in your problem:

At the most basic situation the answer is yes.  What's needed to keep someone alive in space for 48 hours is well within the range of DIY work by someone sufficiently qualified.  You need a pressure hull, 48 hours of air, temperature control and a toilet of some sort.

Your air system can be pretty much off the shelf--a rebreather for scuba diving provides everything you need, just adapt it to blow into the capsule rather than a mouthpiece.

Temperature control can be some white shutters over black panels, combined with a slow roll like Apollo did.

A toilet can simply vent urine and use the yucky Apollo fecal collection bags.

There are three additional aspects to a space capsule, though, and you haven't defined if they're needed.

1. Attitude control.  Two options here:

1a)  Reaction control systems.  Now we are getting into some nasty territory.  Hypergolic propellants are nasty, nasty things and I would be surprised if your backyard engineers can even get their hands on them, nor are the likely to have the equipment to safely handle them.

1b)  Wheels.  Slow, but so long as that is acceptable they'll work.  Three electric motors simply turning weights will do it.

2. Deorbit burn.  Wheels won't help you here, you have to go with rockets--this could be the same ones used for reaction control, although the shuttle used bigger versions of the same idea.
3. Reentry heating.  Highly specialized materials and I would expect some three-letter guys (look at the various government security agencies--most of them have three word names, normally abbreviated to three letters) to come knocking on your door if you even try to get them.  You also have no feasible means to test your design even if you get the material.

Comment: If you don't care about how heavy the system is, heat shielding isn't a problem.  Refractory bricks intended for something like a smelter or kiln should work, and I wouldn't be surprised if you could get away with something as primitive as a good, thick layer of oak.

Comment: Agree these are areas more challenging than others and hypergolic fuels are out. In addition to reaction wheels, could a cold gas thrusters meet this need? They're coming along - see https://spacenews.com/spacety-thrustme-cold-gas-test/

Deorbit burn - solids?

Reentry shield - this seems the most likely part to be overbuilt. Shields with phenolic resin and fiberglass have a solid track record and both ingredients are widely available - phenolic resin is used to make countertops now. Heatshield grade fiberglass might be harder to come by, thus the potential need to overbuild.

Comment: @Mark Overbuilding makes it easier but doesn't address the problem that the primary job of the shield is to reject the heat in the first place.  The capsule is carrying enough energy to vaporize it, that energy must be rejected into the plasma that surrounds the capsule rather than allowed in.

Comment: @KevinMcLeod Cold gas is simple but inefficient--adequate when you don't need much energy (SpaceX uses it returning the first stage because those engines don't put out much thrust per flight and it saves them the headaches of hypergolic fuel), but it's not up to the deorbit burn.  You need a real rocket for that.

Comment: Obviously reaction wheels and cold gas thrusters aren't solutions for the deorbit burn, those are intended for attitude control. I suggested solids for the deorbit burn.

Shield - one of the main functions is to form a bow wave that prevents most of the heat from reaching the capsule. This work has been done since the mid-50s. Shaped correctly and built carefully, it appears doable. See: https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Reentry+Vehicle+Development+Leading+to+the+Minuteman+Avco+Mark+5+and...-a0519403680

Comment: Mark's comment about a slab of oak - may we someday see an orbital version of "Will it blend?"
"Let's try this trilayer of cork, dried cheese and old books on a 12" diameter test capsule, see how it goes,"

Comment: @KevinMcLeod But are you going to ride an untested heat shield when you have no experience building them?!?!

Comment: Who said anything about untested? Of course it would be tested prior to human use. Which is besides the point. The question remains: is it technically doable? I don't see any insuperable barriers. Cost could be one - and I'm sure the folks at Copenhagen Suborbital would agree - but as I stated earlier, we'll set aside cost for this discussion.

Comment: @KevinMcLeod Testing it would require dropping capsules into the atmosphere.  That doesn't seem to be within the parameters of the question, it seems like a one-shot.

Comment: “... could a similarly scaled single-person orbital vehicle capable of *repeatedly* sustaining 48 hours in orbit...”

Not sure how you conclude single shot from that.